# Eclipse Gradle Integration not working

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, gradle, integration

Hello I have to import a gradle proyect to eclipse and the integration doesn't seem to work, Im using Windows 7.

I have installed  the Gradle eclipse integration from  this update site:

https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/

It is installed correctly, how ever it seems like it doesnt have any effect on eclipse..

---

For example I go to:

New -> Proyect -> *And there is no Gradle option.

Import -> *And there is no Gradle option.

---

I have downloaded gradle and copy the folder to C:\gradle\ and added the bin folder to the PATH variable.

Is there something im missing?

ps: I also installed the same things in my Mac and it works, but in my Windows PC it doesnt.

Comment: Sounds like you need to install the eclipse gradle plugin: "Gradle Integration for Eclipse"

Comment: I installed STS 3.6.0 on Windows, Mac and Linux.  Gradle worked out of the box for me on Windows but didn't on Mac or Linux.  There is no preference pane for it either.  I'm yet to work out why (sorry!).

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found was to: 
uninstall eclipse and the android sdk

Download eclipse android bundle (ADT) and all the extra plugins I use.

Download the gradle plugin.

I still don't know why the gradle plugin didn't work on my other eclipse version, and yet it figured as install.